# Spring-security how to login from every page?

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring-MVC application in which I want to have a login bar which is displayed on multiple pages - and uses jQuery's dialog system to display the form in a modal dialog window. What Spring-Security setup should I use in the `securityContext.xml` for this to work?

This is what I currently use:

```xml
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/redirect.jsp" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />        
    <form-login login-page="" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login from every page is another way of saying that the app doesn't have any entry point. So we need to configure an entry point that does nothing.

We can do it as follows:

```
public class DoNothingEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        /* do nothing */

        }
}


in XML:
<beans:bean id="doNothingEntryPoint" class="xyz.package.DoNothingEntryPoint" />

<http entry-point-ref="doNothingEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jsp, you can take advantage of spring tags:

```
<sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">
//User is loggedin
              Welcome, ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.principal.nameToDisplay}
              <a href="j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>
                </sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
//user is not loggedin, show login form
                <form id="loginForm" onsubmit="DoLoginInline();"  target="passwordIframe" >
                <label>Login:</label>
                <input type="text" class="headerInputs" id="LoginUsername" name="j_username">
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="headerInputs" id="LoginPassword" name="j_password">


                <button type="submit" value="Submit"></button>

                </form>

            </sec:authorize>
```